# Spring Security SAML: Passive login with NoPassive status in response

Tags: java, spring, spring-saml

In my current implementation of Spring Secutity SAML extension version 1.0.1.RELEASE, the passive login gives me a stack trace. I want to validate a (possibly) logged in user when the user fires a request.

My entryPoint is defined as:

```xml
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" before="FIRST"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="samlFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

The entryPoint itself is

```xml
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            <property name="passive" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When requesting a passive login the SAML tracker shows me this (omitted several parts not interesting)

```xml
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
             Destination="URI"
             IssueInstant="2015-11-24T10:32:06.864Z"
             Version="2.0"
             >
    ...
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoPassive" />
    </saml2p:Status>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Console output is as follows

```
24 nov 2015 11:32:04 INFO  (org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter:108)     - No default metadata configured, generating with default values, please pre-configure metadata for production use
24 nov 2015 11:32:04 INFO  (org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter:130)     - Created default metadata for system with entityID: http://localhost/webshop
24 nov 2015 11:32:04 INFO  (org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger:127)     - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;http://localhost/webshop;IDPENDPOINT;;;
24 nov 2015 11:32:07 INFO  (org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:130)     - Validation of request simple signature succeeded
24 nov 2015 11:32:07 INFO  (org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:132)     - Authentication via request simple signature succeeded for context issuer entity ID IDPENDPOINT
24 nov 2015 11:32:07 INFO  (org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule:129)     - Validation of protocol message signature succeeded, message type: {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response
```

And the following stacktrace

```
24 nov 2015 11:32:09 INFO  (org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger:127)     - AuthNResponse;FAILURE;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;http://localhost/webshop;IDPENDPOINT;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoPassive, status message is null
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at nl.ns.soaplogger.logging.filter.LogSoapFilter.doFilter(LogSoapFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
at nl.ns.decorator.GenericFrontEndFilter.doFilter(GenericFrontEndFilter.java:51)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

As seen the status code for the message is urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoPassive, which (according to the idp supplier) indicates that the user is not logged in. In our case, we want to serve the application to the user without any pre filled details.

When following the stacktrace, we can see the line on which the error is thrown, and the preceding lines.

```java
    AuthnRequest request = null;
    SAMLObject message = context.getInboundSAMLMessage();

    // Verify type
    if (!(message instanceof Response)) {
        throw new SAMLException("Message is not of a Response object type");
    }
    Response response = (Response) message;

    // Verify status
    String statusCode = response.getStatus().getStatusCode().getValue();
    if (!StatusCode.SUCCESS_URI.equals(statusCode)) {
        StatusMessage statusMessage = response.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
        String statusMessageText = null;
        if (statusMessage != null) {
            statusMessageText = statusMessage.getMessage();
        }
        throw new SAMLException("Response has invalid status code " + statusCode + ", status message is " + statusMessageText);
    }
```

SUCCESS_URI has the following value in StatusCode (from the OpenSAML project)

```
String SUCCESS_URI = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success";
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code concerning passive logins (it works for non-passives) or is there simply no support (yet) for the given status code by the IDP?

Comment: The IDP is not required to support passive logins.  If it does support passive logins, and the user has no current Authn context with the IDP (i.e. no session, or session has expired), then the IDP may still fail if the only way to (re-)authenticate the user is via a non-passive prompt (e.g. ask for username/password or MFA token).  TL;DR - it's a best-effort request, but you should consider falling-back to interactive / non-passive modes.